# Categories of Origins and Destinations in OD Cost Matrix

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, network-analyst

I am using ArcMap 10.8.1

I need to perform the OD cost matrix analysis. Origins can be only linked to specific destinations as seen in the picture (origins from category 1 can be linked only with destinations from category 1 etc.) Since we are not the best friends with Python, I can mainly work with ModelBuilder which does not support two iterators.

Any idea how to solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Python is a willing friend, the easiest computer language to learn, **ever**. I suggest you make its acquaintance.

Comment: Do them all, delete unwanted pairs

Comment: Have you explored using search_query in the Add locations tool to limit your data? Also you could explore using sub-models as you can have an iterator _within_ a submodel that has another iterator. Again thats in the help file.